# gridviewlist column displayed evenly across the gridview docking area

Tags: c#

how would it be possible to dock the contents of a grid view inside the entire grid itself, so the columns are scretched out evenly horizontally across the form?

[What i have](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9v3s4hvlqxj5w5/current.png) | [What i want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2f5whh90ckhot0/want.png)

help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right-click the datagridview
- Click on Properties
- In the Properties window, locate the Columns section and click the tab
- In the dialog that appears locate the AutoSize property for each column and set to Fill

[image]